# Convert std::string to llvm::MemoryBuffer

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am looking to create an LLVM Module from existing LLVM IR code.

The two methods I have found are the following:

- `ParseIRFile` - This accepts a file name and generates a module
- `ParseIR`  - This accepts MemoryBuffer and generates a module

I want to create a Module when the LLVM IR is already read to a string as an `std::string` or `const char *`.

Is there a way to convert an IR string to `llvm::MemoryBuffer` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of a colleague.

This is how you would do it:

```
std::string IRString = readfile("add.ll");
MemoryBuffer *mem = MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(IRString);
```