# How do I get the contents of an llvm::MemoryBuffer as an std::string?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am using the Clang `FileManager` to work with some C++ source-code. For debugging and transformations I would like to get the contents of a file as a string.

I can get an `llvm::MemoryBuffer` using `FileManager::getBufferForFile`.

How do I read the whole `llvm::MemoryBuffer` into an `std::string`?

---

This question is the reverse of [Convert std::string to llvm::MemoryBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273509/convert-stdstring-to-llvmmemorybuffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [API reference](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1MemoryBuffer.html), it seems easy: `std::string str (mb.getBufferStart(), getBufferEnd());`

or [`StringRef`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html) and get the string out of that using `str()`.